# Trouble passing filter (viz-filter) value from Angular application to embedded web-component Tableau report

Tags: angular, tableau-api

I'm having trouble embedding and configuring a Tableau report inside of an Angular 15 app. What I want to do is just pass an initial filter value, and then show the report. Here is a code sample of a report running properly in regular old HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="module" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<tableau-viz id="tableauViz" src="https://public.tableau.com/views/DigitalMarketingWebTraffic/Cockpit?:language=en-US&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link">
    <viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" value="Social" />
</tableau-viz>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine. The report loads, filtered to the proper channelGrouping. However, if I bring this into an Angular context, I cannot get the dynamic value I want to pass to `viz-filter` to bind. This has gotta be something silly, but I can't figure it out.

In my Angular application, I'm including this in my `index.html` page (note that it's different from the referenced version in the above example):

```
<script type="module"
  src="https://embedding.tableauusercontent.com/tableau.embedding.3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

...and then this is the Angular component:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableau-embed',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  template: `<tableau-viz
  id="tableau1"
  src="https://public.tableau.com/views/DigitalMarketingWebTraffic/Cockpit?:language=en-US&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link">
</tableau-viz>`,
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class TableauEmbedComponent {}
```

This works fine.

But as soon as I introduce `viz-filter`, I start to run into weird problems. For example, this works:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableau-embed',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  template: `<tableau-viz
  id="tableau1"
  src="https://public.tableau.com/views/DigitalMarketingWebTraffic/Cockpit?:language=en-US&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link">
  <viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" value="Direct" />
</tableau-viz>`,
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class TableauEmbedComponent {}
```

However, if I try to bind the `value` attribute to an Angular class variable, like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableau-embed',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  template: `<tableau-viz
  id="tableau1"
  src="https://public.tableau.com/views/DigitalMarketingWebTraffic/Cockpit?:language=en-US&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link">
  <viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" [value]="channelGrouping" />
</tableau-viz>`,
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class TableauEmbedComponent {
  channelGrouping = 'Direct';
}
```

...it doesn't work. In the DOM inspector, what I see is literally this:

[image]

The entire `value` attribute just doesn't show up. I've tried this:

```
  <viz-filter field="user_id" [attr.value]="channelGrouping" />
```

...which seems like it does the right thing, in that the DOM inspector shows the `value` attribute, with the proper value passed along:

[image]

...but Tableau doesn't appear to like that because the Tableau report ignores that value, which makes me think it's not really getting passed to Tableau, for whatever reason. (Again, if I hard-code that value in `viz-filter`, then Tableau behaves properly.)

I've also tried this:

```
<viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" value="{{ channelGrouping }}" />
```

and:

```
<viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" attr.value="{{ channelGrouping }}" />
```

...but I get the same issue where I just see `<viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" />`.

And for the sake of completion, if I do this:

```
<tableau-viz
        id="tableauViz"
        src="https://public.tableau.com/views/DigitalMarketingWebTraffic/Cockpit?:language=en-US&:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link">
        <viz-filter field="ga:channelGrouping" [value]="channelGrouping" />
        <div [id]="channelGrouping"></div>
      </tableau-viz>
```

I see this:

[image]

...where the class variable `channelGrouping` is clearly bound to the id attribute of the `div` tag which is a sibling to the `viz-filter` tag.

Here's the start of a Stackblitz which has all the code that should be required for this to run--but of course for some reason this code is not actually working in Stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uch2bk?file=src%2Ftableau-embed.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who stumbles across this, I've figured out one approach that works. I can't say with 100% certainty that this is the "right" way to do this, though it probably is.

The issue is that Angular treats the `value` attribute on `viz-filter` differently than the `src` and `id` attributes on `tableau-viz`. In short, you can't use data binding on `value` in `viz-filter`, and so need to use `Renderer2` to grab that component's native element, and then call `setAttribute` against that. Here's the complete code of the Angular component I'm using to embed a Tableau dashboard:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableau-embed',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  template: `<div #wrapper>
    <tableau-viz
      [id]="vizIndex"
      [src]="url"
      width="{{ screenWidth }}"
      hide-tabs
      toolbar="hidden">
      <viz-filter #vizFilterUserId field="user_id"></viz-filter>
    </tableau-viz>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class TableauEmbedComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  private renderer = inject(Renderer2);

  @Input() dashboardIndex = 0;
  @Input() toolbar = 'hidden';
  @Input() url = '';
  @Input() user_id = '';
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapperElement?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild('vizFilterUserId', { static: false }) vizFilterUserId?: ElementRef;
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onWindowResize() {
    this.calculateDashboardSize();
  }

  initialized = false;
  screenWidth: number = 0;
  vizIndex = `Tableau-Viz-${this.dashboardIndex}`;

  calculateDashboardSize = () => {
    const bufferSize = 25;
    this.screenWidth =
      this.wrapperElement?.nativeElement.offsetWidth || 0 - bufferSize;
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.calculateDashboardSize();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.vizFilterUserId) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
        this.vizFilterUserId.nativeElement,
        'value',
        this.user_id
      );
    }
  }
}
```